# How to make Regex lookahead to match one and two digit numbers?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

Let's say for example that I have a string reading `"1this12string"`. I would like to use `String#split` with regex using lookahead that will give me `["1this", "12string"]`.

My current statement is `(?=\d)`, which works very well for single digit numbers. I am having trouble modifying this statement to include both 1 and 2 digit numbers.

Comment: In other words you want to split in place (a) which has digit *after* it, but at the same time you want to (b) prevent splitting if there is a digit *before*, like in case in place marked with `|` in `"1|2string"`. 

You already have (a) condition expressed via `(?=\d)`. To express condition (b) you can use negative-lookbehind like `(?<!\d)`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a look behind so you don't split *within* numbers:

```
(?<!\d)(?=\d)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/T087cfwYaCI7rk).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use Regex Lookahead, try this:

```
(\d{1,2}[^\d]*)(?=\d|\b)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qZxpkf/1)

Note that this assume every string split must have 1 or 2 digits at the front.  In case this is not the case, please let us know so that we can further enhance it.

### Regex Logics

- `\d{1,2}` to match 1 or 2 digits at the front
- `[^\d]*` to match non-digit characters following the first 1 or 2 digit(s)
- Enclose the the above 2 segments in parenthesis () so as to make it a capturing group for extraction of matched text.
- `(?=\d`  to fulfill your requirement to use Regex Lookahead
- `|\b` to allow the matching text to be at the end of a text (just before a word boundary)

I think you can also achieve your task with a simpler regex, without using the relatively more sophisticated feature like Regex Lookahead.  For example:

```
\d{1,2}[^\d]*
```

You can see in the [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gLKol9/1) that this works equally well for your sample input.  Anyway, in case your requirement is anything more than this, please let us know to fine-tune it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```java
String[] splits = string.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/cGsVPr/1)

**Explanation**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \D                       non-digits (all but 0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```